The double-click listener for the HTML element does not work on iOS version 17.5.1 and above
I wrote the standard code for the double-click listener using JavaScript and Jquery. But I do not know why my code does not work for the mobile version of the site on a device with iOS 17.5.1 and higher.
The web application was added to the iPhone desktop as a shortcut.
I have tried the following:
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
    ...
});

var touchtime = 0;
$('body').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    if (touchtime == 0) {
        touchtime = new Date().getTime();
    } else {
        if (((new Date().getTime()) - touchtime) < 200) {
            ...
            touchtime = 0;
        } else {
            touchtime = new Date().getTime();
        }
    }
});

var tapped=false
    $('body').on("touchstart",function(e){
        if(!tapped){
            tapped = setTimeout(function(){
                tapped=null;
            }, 400);
        } else {
            clearTimeout(tapped);
            tapped=null;
            ...
        }
    });

What could be the mistake?

iPhones may react differently on apps you load from home screen and on the web.
Here is code I tested on iPhone 13 iOS 17.6.1
Mix and match the functions as needed


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let touchtime = 0;
  let tapped = false;

  // Desktop
  document.body.addEventListener('dblclick', (e) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // double-click logic here
    console.log('Double-click detected!');
  });

  // click and touch for mobile (including iOS)
  document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!tapped) {
      tapped = setTimeout(function() {
        tapped = null;
      }, 300); // Use a slightly longer timeout to handle slower double-taps
    } else {
      clearTimeout(tapped);
      tapped = null;
      // double-tap logic here
      console.log('Double-tap detected!');
    }
  });

  // Touch event handler for mobile devices
  document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (touchtime === 0) {
      touchtime = currentTime;
    } else {
      if (currentTime - touchtime < 300) {
        // double-tap logic here
        console.log('Double-tap detected!');
        touchtime = 0;
      } else {
        touchtime = currentTime;
      }
    }
  });
});
<div style="height:50px;width:50px; border:1px solid black;">Click</div>




iOS Safari often handles touch events differently from other browsers. It may have its own handling for double-tap zoom or other gestures. So try other method .

This is really a comment. When you have enough REP you can comment. But please until then do not answer unless you have an actual solution

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
